# How to figure out why torsocks isn't working on OS X

Tags: mac, torsocks

I installed tor and torsocks on OS X 10.11 with brew and then ran tor.

```
$ brew up
$ brew install tor torsocks
$ tor --version
Tor version 0.2.7.6.
$ torsocks --version
Torsocks 2.1.0
$ tor
```

In another terminal window, I checked that the connection to the tor network was OK.

```
$ curl --socks5-hostname localhost:9050 https://check.torproject.org/api/ip
{"IsTor":true,"IP":"81.209.35.112"}
```

However, when I tried to use torsocks, it didn't work.

```
$ torsocks curl https://check.torproject.org/api/ip 
{"IsTor":false,"IP":"XX.XXX.XX.XXX"}
```

I noticed that torsocks is a shell script and tried to reproduce its behaviour with the following commands but it didn't work either.

```
$ export DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=/usr/local/Cellar/torsocks/2.1.0/lib/torsocks/libtorsocks.dylib
$ export DYLD_FORCE_FLAT_NAMESPACE=1
$ curl https://check.torproject.org/api/ip
{"IsTor":false,"IP":"XX.XXX.XX.XXX"}
```

What can I do to debug this problem?

Edit: the IP address returned by https://check.torproject.org is mine, ie. `torsocks curl https://check.torproject.org/api/ip` and `curl https://check.torproject.org/api/ip` return exactly the same output

Edit: tor log

`$ tor
Jan 14 17:16:34.173 [notice] Tor v0.2.7.6 running on Darwin with Libevent 2.0.22-stable, OpenSSL 1.0.2e and Zlib 1.2.5.
Jan 14 17:16:34.174 [notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe at https://www.torproject.org/download/download#warning
Jan 14 17:16:34.175 [notice] Configuration file "/usr/local/etc/tor/torrc" not present, using reasonable defaults.
Jan 14 17:16:34.180 [notice] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9050
Jan 14 17:16:34.000 [notice] Parsing GEOIP IPv4 file /usr/local/Cellar/tor/0.2.7.6/share/tor/geoip.
Jan 14 17:16:34.000 [notice] Parsing GEOIP IPv6 file /usr/local/Cellar/tor/0.2.7.6/share/tor/geoip6.
Jan 14 17:16:34.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 0%: Starting
Jan 14 17:16:34.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 80%: Connecting to the Tor network
Jan 14 17:16:35.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 85%: Finishing handshake with first hop
Jan 14 17:16:35.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 90%: Establishing a Tor circuit
Jan 14 17:16:35.000 [notice] Tor has successfully opened a circuit. Looks like client functionality is working.
Jan 14 17:16:35.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 100%: Done`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found some clues reading this question: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/212586/torsocks-not-working-in-el-capitan

Suppose I installed httpie with brew

```
$ brew install httpie
```

The following command line won't have expected result:

```
$ torsocks http https://check.torproject.org/api/ip
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 35
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Tue, 19 Jan 2016 11:12:30 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=15
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15768000
Via: 1.1 check.torproject.org

{ 
    "IP": "XX.XX.XX.XXX", 
    "IsTor": false
}
```

But if I install httpie with pip instead of brew

```
$ brew uninstall httpie
$ brew install python
$ pip install httpie
```

The same command line will use tor.

```
$ torsocks http https://check.torproject.org/api/ip
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 35
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Tue, 19 Jan 2016 11:06:08 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=15
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15768000
Via: 1.1 check.torproject.org

{ 
    "IP": "195.154.56.44", 
    "IsTor": true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the IP shown yours? If it's not - it's just a bug in an external detector you're using. Not all the exit nodes are detectable =)

Comment: Yes, the IP is mine. I'll edit the question to clarify.

Comment: @yansal have you tried to check the SOCKS functionality? can you paste Tor log here?

Comment: What do you mean by "checking the SOCKS functionality" ? I'll edit the question to add tor log

Comment: @yansal have you tried to pass through SOCKS proxy something like HTTP/HTTPS from another system and have seen it working? i.e. verify the SOCKS working. In your log I see no problems at all, it seems cURL wasn't talking to it. try to replace localhost with 127.0.0.1 and paste your `torrc` - are SocksPolicy directives OK?

Answer (score 0):

I believe to use torsocks you use the handy torify wrapper and it just works, e.g. from yours above: `torify curl https://check.torproject.org/api/ip`

I used this method at the time of this writing to curl my own domain jamescampbell.us and it worked fine.

To test on something that is actually a .onion site, try the duckduckgo onion url:

`torify curl 3g2upl4pq6kufc4m.onion` and check your results.

If you get resolution errors, you can try the direct approach with curl domain resolution turned off that is built-in to curl (note the socks5-hostname vs socks5):

`curl --socks5-hostname 127.0.0.1:9050 3g2upl4pq6kufc4m.onion`

Hope that at least points you in the right direction.

Comment: Using torify instead of torsocks doesn't work. Using one or another returns the exact same input. Using the `--socks5-hostname` option in curl works, but is irrelevant because I would like to use other command line utilities which don't have that option.

Comment: @yansal have you tried proxychains-ng? It allows you to wrap any command line util in a list of proxies you set. I have found this to be the best approach besides setting up privoxy and routing traffic that way or writing code in python and using the STEM package.

Comment: I will have a look, but I would really prefer keeping the setup as simple as possible

Comment: @yansal to implement there is a single conf file and you run it the same way as torify & torsocks but as proxychains4 before each command instead.